# Object property overwrites

Tags: javascript, web

Doing a tutorial...came across:

```
let user1 = { name: 'Bob' };
let user2 = { name: 'Ross' };
let total = {};
total[user1] = 5;
total[user2] = 42;
```

Why does total user1 get overwritten to 42?  I imagine this all looking like this now:

total = {{ user1 = { name: 'Bob' } : 5}, { user2 = { name: 'Ross' } : 42 };

So total contains two object properties which map to value 5 and 42?  How do you access the name properties in total[user1] and total[user2]?  Also, why does 42 overwrite the 5?  I can't see exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you attempt to use an object as a key for another object, the object meant to be a key is first converted to a string by calling `toString` on that object. Unless overridden, `toString` on every object always returns `"[object Object]"`. So, when you use *any* object as a key, you're instead using the string `"[object Object]"` for *all* objects which haven't defined their own `toString` method, as is the case in your example. When you assign to a key in an object, it overwrites whatever previous value it had, and so you get the result you see. If you'd like this to be different for an object, you can overwrite the `toString` method to return something different, for example:

```
const example = {test: "This is a test"};
const overwritten = {test: "This is a test"};
overwritten.toString = function(){
                           return '{test: "This is a test"}';
                       };
let all = {};
all[example] = 1;
all[overwritten] = 2;

// all == {"[object Object]": 1, '{test: "This is a test"}': 2}
```